# Check Whether Incoming Call to Web Service is over Https

Tags: c#, asp.net

We want to make sure any calls that are coming into our .asmx are https.  I'm not sure how/where to check that.  In our asmx I assume I can check the HttpContext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this property:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

Comment: what would be the difference of doing this: HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

Comment: creating an actual instance vs. how you're just referring to it in a static way?

Comment: For your purposes, the difference is probably irrelevant as your HttpContext is only valid for the duration of the web service call anyway (HttpContext encapsulates the current request only).  I would stick to using it how I've listed it though, unless you see a reason not to?